# Milliseconds from GETUTCDATE not stored in datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have stored procedure that inserts data into table. One column in the table is datetime and is used for storing the time stamp of row insert:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES (1, 2, GETUTCDATE());
```

`Field3` is datetime column. When I select data from that table with simple `SELECT * FROM myTable` query, all datetime values are shown with `.000` value for milliseconds.

If I execute `SELECT GETUTCDATE()`, the milliseconds are displayed: `2013-10-16 18:02:55.793`

Why milliseconds are not stored/displayed in the date time column on SELECT?

Comment: Are you retrieving this column through an application?

Comment: No, all queries are executed in SSMS.

Comment: What is the datatype for the column where you are storing these values ??? by any chance is it  smalldatetime ???

Comment: Column is datetime, that is sure.

Comment: What does `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), DatetimeColumn, 126) FROM table;` show?

Comment: Output: 2013-10-16T14:14:00, 2013-10-16T14:28:01...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be doing something somewhere to change this to smalldatetime or something because it works fine. I just created a new table, inserted data like you showed, queried the table and I have the milliseconds.

I have been unable to find anything where you can set the precision at the server level so it must be in your code.

Comment: I understand your point but for some reason this does not work on my server. Value is passed to the table directly from GETUTCTIME() so there is no room for changing the type to smalldatetime.

Comment: So you do get the seconds, but not the milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, seconds are fine but millisecond for each record is .000

Comment: So run this, and post the result:  create table TestTime (Test datetime)
GO
insert into TestTime (Test) values (getutcdate())
GO
SELECT Test from TestTime
GO
Drop table TestTime
GO

Comment: Any luck? what's the result?

Comment: Hi Steve, your test works as expected - milliseconds are stored and displayed. Your initial answer is also correct, "something somewhere" is changing the data and issue was not related with server. I found that third party created a trigger on this table, that trigger does milliseconds rounding on insert. Thank you on your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Which datetime type are you using? To store the date with precision up to a millisecond, you need to use `DATETIME2` if you're using SQL Server 2008 or higher.

'DATETIME' gives a precision of about 1/300th of a second.

'SMALLDATETIME' has accuracy of 1 minute.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2284256/steve) suggested, issue was not related with server. There is a trigger on this table, that trigger does milliseconds rounding on insert.